# Uncaught ReferenceError: Strings is not defined clienttemplates.js?rev=J%2BGzwlHEWSv11%2BqD9XeOaw%3D%3D:1

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sharepoint

I am facing some problems when view SharePoint 2013 Apps , using Google chrome. so i use the chrome developer tool to track these error and the consule is showing the following error :-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Strings is not defined clienttemplates.js?rev=J%2BGzwlHEWSv11%2BqD9XeOaw%3D%3D:1
$_global_clienttemplates clienttemplates.js?rev=J%2BGzwlHEWSv11%2BqD9XeOaw%3D%3D:1
(anonymous function) clienttemplates.js?rev=J%2BGzwlHEWSv11%2BqD9XeOaw%3D%3D:
```

so what might be causing this error , baring in mind that if i access the SharePoint using IE, FireFox or safari it will work fine. so the exception is happening on chrome only.

Comment: We'll need to see some code, but judging by the error, there is a variable `Strings` that is `undefined`.

Comment: what type of code,, i am customizing my sharePoint web application ?

Answer (score 1):

Load your scripts first

```
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['sp.js', 'clienttemplates.js','clientforms.js','clientpeoplepicker.js','autofill.js'], function(){
//your function here

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to get a relative date by calling the SP.DateTimeUtil.SPRelativeDateTime.getRelativeDateTimeString function.  Apparently this function has issues.  I dumped it and used the timeago jquery script found here [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js)

Answer (score 0):

The object `Strings` is defined in `sts_strings.js`, located in a language-specific subfolder of the `layouts` folder. For example, assuming you have an English version: `/_layouts/15/1033/sts_strings.js`. You should include this `JavaScript` reference before the reference for `clienttemplates.js`.